# jsch and running sudo from a particular directory

Tags: java, linux

I have connected to remote ubuntu server. On connection, i want to execute below shell commands

```
String command = "cd "to some directory" ; 
sudo ./i3lsdd"; 
// want to move to a directory and execute sudo ./i3lsdd command.
```

I have used the below code but it is giving this error:

> "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified Sorry, try
>   again."

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

keep the command "sudo ./i3lsdd" in .sh file in home directory.

Get Home directory path using

```
String path = channelSftp.pwd();
```

Write the command as below

```
String command = "sudo -S " + path + "/scriptname.sh";
```

Provide the password with below code

```
out1.write((sudo_pass + "\n").getBytes()); 
out1.flush();
```